# posting the respinse from an ajax call to another page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting a Json array as response from an ajax call, I want to post this Json array data immediately to another page and redirect to that page. Does anyone know how I can do that

```
 $.post("flightsearch/searchhome.php",{
                    fromairport2  : fromairport1,
                    toairport2    : toairport1
                }, function(data){
                       alert(data);
                       //var response = data;
                       //window.location.replace("flight-detail.php");
                });
```

I want to post the response data i am getting to that page and redirecting to that page at the same time

Comment: Can you provide your workings so far to show us where exactly you have progressed to? We can't tell you how to solve your problem unless you show us workings.

Comment: If you make an AJAX request then redirect anyway, the AJAX request is completely pointless. I'd suggest you double check your logic here.

Comment: I have improved the question and added my code

Comment: @Dammson, I've created a snippet for you to view the process.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan, I think if i redirect anyway, i wont be able to pass the data to the next page and i dont want to use something like this windows.location.replace("flight-detail.php?id="+ data);   the array is too large to send to the other page that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've captured your `JSON`, create a jQuery object of a form with the associated input fields. Once the form is created, submit it. I'm only removing it to prevent it from showing on the users screen during the load.

```js
/* Bind Click Event to Button */
$('button').on('click', function() {
    /* Set Empty jQuery Form Object */
    var formObject = $('<form/>', { method: 'POST' });
    
    /* Fetch JSON */
    $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', function(response) {
        /* Itererate Through Response */
        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
            /* Append jQuery Input Object w/ Associated Name/Value to Form Object */
            $('<input/>', { name: key, value: value }).appendTo(formObject);
        });
        
        /* Append Form Object to Body, Submit, and Remove */
        formObject.appendTo('body').submit().remove();
    });
});

/* Delegating Form Submission on Body to Prevent Submission to Show Console Log */
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
});
```

```html
<body>
    <button>Fetch JSON and POST</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I am not sure that will work in this scenario @ Daerik,  really appreciate that

Comment: `I am getting a Json array as response from an ajax call, I want to post this Json array data immediately to another page and redirect to that page` - That's exactly what the function does. Are you saying you needed other functionality that you did not mention in your question?

Comment: Your code snippet works just fine but not suitable for the what i want..

Comment: @Dammson, please revise your question to address specifically what you need. This answer addresses what was requested: to pass a single-dimension JSON array to another page and redirect the user to the same page.

Comment: It's been solved, parsed it through a php session variable rather than parsing it through a post in jquery